# I need to understand why this is happening in swift closures

Tags: swift, closures

```
var a = 6
var t = { [a] in
    print(a)
    
}
a = 8
t()
```

In this example I am not able to send any argument to my closure t, why is this happening

Comment: Because `[a]` is the syntax to capture an existing variable that is in scope. Remove the brackets. You’ll also need to annotate a type.

Comment: To annotate a type, try `let t: ((Int) -> Void) = { a in print(a) }`. Then you can do `t(a)` to pass in the argument.

Comment: @jnpdx thank you so much for the answer I was just confused between [a] and a while capturing

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a closure that takes an Integer parameter, or one that captures a variable from it's enclosing scope?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to define a closure that takes an Int parameter, define your closure using an explicit type:

```
var t:(Int)->Void = {z in
    print("parameter = \(z)")
}
```

If you want to reference a variable from the enclosing scope, just reference it:

```
var a: Int = 3
var t:(Int)->Void = {z in
    print("parameter = \(z). a = \(a)")
}

for z in 1...10 {
    a = z * 2
    t(z)
}
```

That outputs:

```
parameter = 1. a = 2
parameter = 2. a = 4
parameter = 3. a = 6
parameter = 4. a = 8
parameter = 5. a = 10
parameter = 6. a = 12
parameter = 7. a = 14
parameter = 8. a = 16
parameter = 9. a = 18
parameter = 10. a = 20
```

Comment: Oops. You're right. I should have looked more closely.